# i want the all arrays value checked to the value in the number field in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want the all arrays value checked to the value in the number field in javascript. How can I do it ?

```
demoP = document.getElementById("demo");
var numbers = [4, 9, 16, 25];

    function myFunction() {
    if( $("#hsc").value == numbers)
    {
    demoP.style.display = 'none';}
     else
     {
      demoP.style.display = 'block';
     }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code as comments -- edit your original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var demoP = document.getElementById("demo");
var numbers = [4, 9, 16, 25];

function myFunction(data) {
    //console.log(typeof data)
    if (numbers.indexOf(Number(data))>=0) {
        demoP.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        demoP.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" onchange="myFunction(this.value)" id="hsc">Try it 
<p id="demo" style="display:none;">wrong</p>
```

`numbers.indexOf` to get whether value is present or not.

Comment: In numbers.indexOf(Number(data))>=0  what is the use of "Number"

Comment: @Aastik typeof value of input field always gives you string, and in your array all are number to check that i am converting input value to `Number` then checking in array

Comment: i think there is numbers.indexOf(data)>=0

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use `Array.indexOf` to compare the value against an array

```
var demoP   = document.getElementById("demo");
var hsc     = document.getElementById("hsc");
var numbers = [4, 9, 16, 25];

function myFunction() {
    if( numbers.indexOf( +hsc.value ) !== -1){
        demoP.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        demoP.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Comment: `includes` is also a viable option

Comment: Wouldn't you need to add 1 since 0 is a valid index?

Comment: Guys can u give some more answers, this one didnt work.